# Admob native extension rotates app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, admob, flashdevelop, starling-framework

I developed an app with starling in FlashDevelop.

I purchased the admob native extension from milkmangames.com.

The normal banners work as normal.

When I try to show an interstital, it works well.

Upon closing the modal interstital ad, the app switches the orientation,
from landscape left right to landscape right left.

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In your air manifest set your orientation to landscape, this way it will never change the orientation.